# How to JSF loop write in JavaScript tags?

Tags: javascript, jsf

I'm writing loop into javascript for JSF. 
This code block  ***title: '#{userBean.userList[0].name}'*** is running but I want to use in loop. For example  **title: '#{userBean.userList[i].name}'**

```
 <script>


        $(document).ready(function () {

            var events = [];
            for(var i =0; i &lt; #{userBean.userList.size()}; i++) 
            {
                events.push( {
                    title: '#{userBean.userList[i].name}', 
                    start: new Date('#{userBean.userList[i].createDate}'), 
                    end: new Date('#{userBean.userList[i].date}')
                });
            }

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                events: events,
                eventColor: '#3A87AD',
            });

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: I think `hibertnate` tag is wrong here.

Comment: if we put specific index there it works truly but when put it in i not works.